# How to send a JS file from Nodejs enviroment for usage in client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I can't seem to find the answer. My client is asking me for a plain JS file for him to use in HTML. It's a contact form made in Nodejs.

My folders are like this:

```
contact-form
 -bin
 -node_modules
 -public
   -images
   -javascripts
   -stylesheets
     -style.css
-routes
  -index.js
  -users.js
-views
-app.js
-package.json
-package-lock.json
```

Comment: What's the logic of the contact form doing?

Comment: It’s a simple contact form. Name, email, message and submit. The form has validation in the front and the back end. The data is submitted to a mail server. Just that. He want to test it in his webpage just by using a plain JavaScript file and compressed or “minified”.

Comment: @MauroGarcia — It's not clear what the problem is here. Either you are asking how to port code which depends on Node.js so it can run in the browser (which can't be done) or how to write a JS file to generate an HTML form and then how to minify it (which is rather too broad for an SO question)

Comment: He wants to run the contact form (with all the functionality) without a nodejs environment (copy and paste it in the html from the inspect tool from the browser). I told him that it’s not possible to achieve what he wants but he continues asking me to send the file to him. I thought in doing it with plain js but it would have no functionality.

Comment: Which file in your folder structure contains the contact form?

Comment: index.js . All the code is inside that file. It’s a router.post() with all the logic inside. And the requirements in the outer scope, of course.

Comment: It’s the views folder index.pug. But the problem is not that, is the JavaScript function that was built in nodejs. I think I’ll just use something like formspree or plain js for him to use it anywhere.